# remove table column by column name using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove table column by column name using `jquery`? I have already code, to remove column in table by using index:

```
$("" + tblNat + " tr").find('td:eq(1),th:eq(1)').remove();`
```

But now I need to remove table column by column name.

Comment: Also add `HTML` code

Comment: Add the column name as a data attribute to each of its associated cells and target that attribute.

Comment: As Andy says, then you can write like `var index = $(target).index()` to get the index in `tr`

Answer (score 4):

I created a snippet about how to do it.

```js
function remove(str) {
  // Get target th with the name you want to remove.
  var target = $('table').find('th[data-name="' + str +'"]');
  // Find its index among other ths 
  var index = (target).index();
  // For each tr, remove all th and td that match the index.
   $('table tr').find('th:eq(' + index + '),td:eq(' + index + ')' ).remove();
}
remove('A');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <th data-name="A">A</th>
     <th data-name="B">B</th>
     <th data-name="C">C</th>
     <th data-name="D">D</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
     <td> 2</td>
     <td> 3</td>
     <td> 4</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
     <td> 2</td>
     <td> 3</td>
     <td> 4</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: this is the cleanest answer - except the very obvious syntax error which I corrected

Comment: @showdev `$('table')` and `$('table tr')` should be and `$('#table')` and `$('#table tr')`

Comment: @kev The `<table>` does not have an ID of "table".

Comment: ah i didn't notice that, my bad

Answer (score 1):

## HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td>Col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## Javascript

```
var col_name = "Col2"; //hide all cell in col 2.

$("table tr:eq(0) td").each(function(i){

    //search in each header td the name of col 
    if($(this).text() !== "Col2") return;

    //if match
    $("table tr > td:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").hide();
    return false;
});
```

#### working example

http://fiddle.jshell.net/juLcze3j/

Answer (score 1):

Add a data attribute to each cell associated with that column (you can use this method to remove rows too - just add a `data-row` attribute). This example allows you to click on the column heading and the column will be removed.

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>two</th>
        <th>three</th>
        <th>four</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td data-col="one">1</td><td data-col="two">2</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-col="one">1</td><td data-col="two">2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('th').on('click', function () {
  var id = $(this).html();
  $(this).remove();
  $('[data-col="' + id + '"]').remove();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uxz6v89h/16/)

Answer (score 0):

The following works based on the index of the clicked item, be it `TD` or `TH`. Try clicking on any of the `td` or `th` and the corresponding column will be removed.

I have also created a `select` from the column names and a `button` to remove the selected column.

Feel free to ask if you wanted something different or adapt the code accordingly.

```js
//Remove when clicked on any TD or TH
var $table = $('table').on("click", "th, td", function() {
    
    var $this = $(this);
    var index = $this.index();
    if ( $this[0].tagName === "TD" ) {
        $table.find("th").eq(index).remove();
    } else {
        $this.remove();
    }
    $table.find("tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find("td").eq(index).remove();
    });
});

//Remove based on button click
var $ths = $("th").map(function() {
    return "<option>" + $.trim($(this).text()) + "</option>"
}).get();
var $select = $("select").append($ths.join(""));

$(":button").on("click", function() {
    var $option = $select.find(":selected");
    var selected = $option.text();
    $option.remove();
    if ($select.is(':empty')) {
        $select.remove();
        $(this).remove();
    }
    $table.find("th:contains('" + selected + "')").click();
});
```

```css
td, th { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Name1</td><td>Age1</td><td>City1</td><td>Country1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name2</td><td>Age1</td><td>City1</td><td>Country1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name3</td><td>Age1</td><td>City1</td><td>Country1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name4</td><td>Age1</td><td>City1</td><td>Country1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name5</td><td>Age1</td><td>City1</td><td>Country1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br/><br/>
<select></select>&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove Selected" />
```

Hope that helps.